# How to connect the controller with the view and vice versa?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, mvp, signals-slots

I'm developing a little app in C++ using the MVP pattern, but I'm not able to connect the controller with the view and vice versa to exchange signals and slots.

This is the overview of my application:
[image]

In particular, from the menu bar, when I choose a QAction, a window opens with fields to fill in. Once you have filled in the fields of the window and pressed the "Add service" button, I should be able to send the signal to the controller (by means of a triggered() signal) which will have to notify the model (to add a new service in the container). This model, as soon as it has added the service in the container, will have to emit a signal (serviceAdded() that the container will have to "capture" and then do other things (update the view with the services present in the container and close the open window to add service). I wanted to understand how to connect the controller and the view when: the QPushButton is pressed to add the service and how to close the window, after receiving the signal from the model.

[image]

I set up the controller like this:

```
class Controller : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
private:
    Model * model;
    MainView * view;
public:
    explicit Controller(Model * m, MainView * mv);
```

While my main view is set up like this:

```
class Controller;

class MainView : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QHBoxLayout* mainLayout;
    QTableWidget* table;
    QMenuBar* menu;
    Controller * controller; 
public:
    explicit MainView(QWidget *parent=nullptr);
```

When QAction (QAction * artGenerico) is pressed, this happens:

```
connect(artGenerico, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(articoloGenericoWindow()));
```

This code is part of the view.

And “articoloGenericoWindow()” is:

```
void MainView::articoloGenericoWindow(){
ArticoloGenericoView * w = new ArticoloGenericoView();
w->show();
connect(controller, SIGNAL(closeWindow()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

Also this code is part of the view.

The problem is that the controller is not connected to anything, even the compiler tells me: “QObject:: connect: Cannot connect (nullptr):: closeWindow () to MainView:: close ()”. In fact, the window does not close when I click on the button.

How can I connect the controller with the view?

I hope I have expressed myself correctly.

Comment: You said it yourself. controller is nullptr. How do you initialize controller and pass it in? And there seems to be a circular dependency or not correct design. How does MainView have a member of Controller, and Controller has a member of MainView. Stepback and think about the design?

Comment: I tried to make a setting method which has as argument a pointer to Controller.. then I assign this pointer to the controller of the view.. but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: You're not initializing it correctly then. Or your default constructors are wrong. To confirm you can try: connect(Controller(&Model, &MainView()), SIGNAL(closeWindow()), this, SLOT(close()));

Comment: They are probably wrong.. What can I do?
Because even if I set the pointer to QWidget as the only argument of the constructor and keep two pointers as data fields, one to the model and one to the view, somehow I have to initialize these two..

Comment: you have cyclic ref in the code, controller needs a view and view needs a controller??

Comment: Yes.. I'd like to use the MVP pattern.. the view is connected to the presenter and the presenter is connected to the view... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you also have a problem of this type, I solved it by connecting the model and the view to the controller and the view to the controller simply by creating setting methods (in the controller and in the view) and connecting everything in the main.

This is the main:

```
MainView w;
Controller c;
Model m;

c.setModel(&m);
c.setView(&w);
w.setController(&c);
w.show();
```

The setters for the controller:

```
void Controller::setModel(Model* m) {
    model=m;
}
void Controller::setView(MainView* mv) {
    view=mv;
}
```

The setter for the view:

```
void MainView::setController(Controller * c){
    controller=c;
    connect(...)
}
```

In the constructors I simply defined the QWidget:

```
explicit MainView(QWidget *parent=nullptr);
```

Implementation:

```
MainView::MainView(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent){...}
```

Enjoy!